# retrieve value from textbox that is not on the current pagination - datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using VB.Net, MVC, Razor, javaScript and jQuery with the Datatables plugin.  I am rendering a table that contains text boxes.  The user is allowed to type values into these text boxes and submit the values to the database.

Everything works fine as long as the table is only one page long.  In the event that the table is multiple pages, only the values that are visible are submitted.  However if the user enters values on page one, moves to page two, then back to page one, the values that were typed into the text boxes are still there.  This leads me to believe the values are still on the web page somewhere.  I am currently using javaScript `getElementsByClassName` to retrieve the values.

Here is how my table is rendered:

```
<tbody>
    @For i As Integer = 0 To Model.History.Count - 1
        @<tr>
            <td>@Model.History(i).Quarter</td>
        @If Model.History(i).MeterUsage < 0 Then
            @<td>
                <input class="edit" id="@(Model.History(i).dateToRecord)" type="text" placeholder="meter usage" />
            </td>
        Else
            @<td>@Model.History(i).MeterUsage</td>
        End If                         
            <td>@Model.History(i).KeyOperator</td>
            <td>@Model.History(i).BackUpKeyOperator</td>
        </tr>
    Next
</tbody>
```

Here is my javaScript:

```
function submitChanges(changes) {
    var changes = document.getElementsByClassName('edit');
        var myChanges = {
            listOfIDs: [],
            listOfValues: []
        };
}
```

Is there some way to capture the values that are entered on page 1 of the table, when the user is viewing another page of the table?

Comment: You are right! Values are there in invisible state. You just need to differentiate them from visible values!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`$()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/%24%28%29) API method to get access to all elements in the table.

```
function submitChanges(changes) {
    var changes = $('#example').DataTable().$('.edit');
    var myChanges = {
       listOfIDs: [],
       listOfValues: []
    };
}
```

Replace `example` with your actual table ID.